# Python while loop boolean only showing as True

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, boolean

I'm having trouble. I want the code to loop through and ask `'Hey, are you hungry?'` but only if the hungry variable isn't `True` or `False`. However, whatever answer I type in, it acts as if it's `True`.

In my head, if I type a variation of yes, then hungry should be `True` and the code should stop. If I type a variation of no then the code should be `False` and stop. If I type neither of these then hungry will not be `True` or `False` and should loop through, asking the question again.

```
hungry = None
while hungry != True or False:
    hungry = input('Hey, are you hungry?')
    if hungry == 'yes' or 'ye' or 'y' or 'yeah':
        print ('oh you hungry huh')
        hungry = True
    elif hungry == 'no' or 'n' or 'nah' or 'nope':
        print ('no food for you then')
        hungry = False
    else:
        print ('its a simple yes or no question pls')
```

Comment: Type in 'True or False' at the REPL and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `hungry == 'yes' or 'ye' or 'y' or 'yeah'` doesn't check if any of `hungry == 'yes'` or `hungry == 'ye'` or `hungry == 'y'` or `hungry == 'yeah'` is true. It checks `(hungry == yes) or 'ye' or 'y' or 'yeah'` (and nothing but `hungry == yes` has a truth value)

Similarly `hungry != True or False` is checking `(hungry != True) or False` so the `False` part of the conditional doesn't do anything.

You should write it as:

```
hungry = None
while hungry not in (True, False):
    hungry = input('Hey, are you hungry?')
    if hungry in ('yes', 'ye', 'y', 'yeah'):
        print ('oh you hungry huh')
        hungry = True
    elif hungry in ('no', 'n', 'nah', 'nope'):
        print ('no food for you then')
        hungry = False
    else:
        print ('its a simple yes or no question pls')
```

Comment: I think there's an opportunity here for some education.  the hungry variable goes from None, to a boolean, to a string, to a boolean, etc.  It's workable in this little scenario, but I don't think the OP will learn much out of this approach. I've added an answer below to explain.

Comment: Good point. My focus was to get what they had written working, but it's definitely bad style to keep changing the type of hungry.

Comment: But impressive on how you were able to keep to the original style ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here, not least is using the same variable name for a few different purposes which is not good style, and also not really using the control flow primitives in python - look it up (https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop).

A concise a working solution would look as follows:

```
while True:
    hungry = input('hungry?')
    if hungry in ('y','yes'):
        print('Eat up')
        break
    elif hungry in ('n','no'):
        print('Ok not hungry')
        break
    else:
        print('You need to tell me')
```

What we've got above is:

- We're starting an infinite loop (while True)
- We're assigning the user input to the hungry variable - and that's all it holds
- If the user enters a variant on 'yes' or 'no' it prints a response and breaks out of the while loop
- if they don't provide a yes/no answer, it goes back to the beginning of the loop again (ie no break)

Answer (score 0):

You can't say `if x == a or b or c` in Python and have it do what you want. You need to use `if x in [a, b, c]` instead.

Comment: Or you can also use `if x in (a, b, c)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
hungry = None
while hungry not in (True, False):
    hungry = input('Hey, are you hungry?')
    if hungry in ('yes', 'ye', 'y', 'yeah'):
        print('oh you hungry huh')
        hungry = True
    elif hungry in ('no', 'n', 'nah', 'nope'):
        print('no food for you then')
        hungry = False
    else:
        print('its a simple yes or no question pls')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are writing code like it is english. When you are comparing a variable to two booleans you to first compare the variable to the first boolean and then compare the variable to the second boolean. So `while hungry != True or False` should be `while hungry != True or hungry != False`. If you use the later, you will get the wrong answer. Do the same for all your other `if` and `while` statements. So your code should be:

```
hungry = None
while hungry != True or hungry == False:
    hungry = input('Hey, are you hungry?')
    if hungry == 'yes' or hungry == 'ye' or hungry == 'y' or hungry == 'yeah':
        print ('oh you hungry huh')
        hungry = True
    elif hungry == 'no' or hungry =='n' or hungry =='nah' or hungry =='nope':
        print ('no food for you then')
        hungry = False
    else:
        print ('its a simple yes or no question pls')
```

Edit:
Others are suggesting membership statements which work too. However, since it looks like you're a beginner from the code you have written, I think my explanation will be easier for you to understand.

Comment: You're right, I haven't covered membership statements, and your code is familiar with what I have covered so far. However I found Pdubbs the most useful as it looks cleaner with less code and I didn't know about the in statements beforehand. Thanks for the help

Comment: @NathanByrne Yeah, I understand. No problem. It was my pleasure.

Comment: Note, you can write hungry != True or False, but python short circuit evaluation on or  will return True, so the comparison is always hungry != True

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because you're using statements in the wrong way, such as `hungry != True or False`, here's a working version of your code:

```
hungry = None
while hungry not in (True, False): # Check if hungry is not True or False
    hungry = input('Hey, are you hungry?')
    if hungry in ('yes', 'ye', 'y', 'yeah'):
        print ('oh you hungry huh')
        hungry = True
    elif hungry in ('no', 'n', 'nah', 'nope'):
        print ('no food for you then')
        hungry = False
    else:
        print ('its a simple yes or no question pls')
```